# Redis SRANDMEMBER with a pattern?

Tags: redis

In Redis, let's say I have a set called animals.
`127.0.0.1:6379> sadd animals cat:bob cat:fred dog:joe dog:rover hamster:harvey`

I know I can use `SRANDMEMBER` to pull a random member from the set, which might be any of the values.
And I know I can get all cats out of the set with something like `SSCAN animals 0 MATCH cat:*`

But is there a way to retrieve a random cat?

Edit for clarity: My example has the important designator at start of string, but I'm looking for something that follows a general pattern where the "match" might be anywhere within the string.

Comment: Why not put cats into a set, and dogs to another set?

Comment: Because this is a gross oversimplification of the actual set I'm building.

Comment: You can put all animals into a set, while build different indexes for each kind of animals, i.e. create dependent set for each animal.

Answer (score 1):

Not in a single command. If you are using a Sorted Set, you can get ranges of values based on the lexical content:

```
> ZADD animals 0 cat:bob 0 cat:fred 0 dog:joe 0 dog:rover 0 hamster:harvey
> ZRANGESTORE cats animals [cat: (cau BYLEX
> ZRANDMEMBER cats
> DEL cats
```

Note that `[cat:` means "range staring with cat, inclusive" and `(cau` means "range ending with cau, exclusive". I picked "cau" because it would be next in the sequence and would only pick cats.

This is, admittedly, a bit of a hack.

Comment: An interesting idea... but with my generalization for my example, I failed to mention that the string "cat" might not be at the start of the string. I was just trying to make it simple. I still could use this for something though.

Comment: The only other way I can think to do this would be to write a Lua script.